# I'm trying to denoise a colored image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

```
 Mat dimg=imread("mata.jpg");
 Mat result;

 void fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(InputArray dimg, OutputArray result, float h=3, float
 hColor=3, int templateWindowSize=7, int searchWindowSize=21 );     

 namedWindow("denoised Image",1);
 imshow("denoised Image",result);

 /// Wait until user press some key
 waitKey();
 return 0;
```

I'm getting the following assert:

> assertion failed in cv::imshow

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mat dimg=imread("mata.jpg");
Mat result;

if ( dimg.empty() ) // only fools don't check !
{
   cerr << "could not load image !";
}

// you have to call the actual function, not copy/paste the declaration !
fastNlMeansDenoisingColored( dimg, result, 3, 3, 7, 21 );     

namedWindow("denoised Image",1);
imshow("denoised Image",result);

/// Wait until user press some key
waitKey();
return 0;
```

Comment: When I compile the code, it gives " error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,float,float,int,int)" (?fastNlMeansDenoisingColored@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@MMHH@Z) referenced in function _main fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals" as error......

Comment: you have to link opencv_photo249.lib (d at the end for debug)